# Marshalling a structure to byte array only works for single bytes?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to serialize a structure to disk as raw bytes. This is a (simplified)version of it.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class TestData :BaseStructure
{
    public byte[] bytes = new byte[]{65,66,67}; // this doesn't write ABC as expected
}
```

A `write` function uses `ConvertStructureToBytes` method to convert this to a byte array and a binary writer then writes it.

```
    public void Write(BaseStructure baseStructure)
    {
        binaryWriter.Write(ConvertStructureToBytes(baseStructure));
    }
```

The `ConvertStructureToBytes` section

```
 public byte[] ConvertStructureToBytes(BaseStructure baseStructure)
    {
        int len = Marshal.SizeOf(baseStructure);
        byte[] arr = new byte[len];

        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(baseStructure, ptr,false);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, len);

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return arr;
    }
```

If I replace the bytes line to

```
public byte byte = 65; // This now writes an A , as expected
```

I have tried

```
public byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABC"); //doesn't work either
```

This probably has something to do with the `ConvertStructureToBytes` function , it isn't treating the byte array as it should.

What do I need to do to be able to write 'ABC' successfully?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What is `BaseStructure`? Your `TestData` class inherits from it, but you are not serialising a `TestData` instance but a `BaseStructure` instance, which is not aware of the data declared in the `TestData` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems.  First your structure declaration is not correct, you have to in-line the array so it no longer a pointer:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class TestData {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 65, 66, 67 };
}
```

Then your ConvertStructureToBytes() method is not correct, it is only ever going to marshal BaseStructure.  You need to make it generic:

```
public static byte[] ConvertStructureToBytes<T>(T baseStructure) {
    // rest the same...
}
```

Do note the kind of trouble you can get into with this approach, it most certainly is not a universal way to marshal data.  Only very specific classes can be serialized this way.  That [MarshalAs] attribute is of course *very* painful to maintain.  You might as well use binary serialization.

Comment: Thank you, this WORKS! Yay... I am actually writing raw bytes for ISO9660 structure and the classes involved are directories,files and path tables, all predefined and the fields, such as bytes above wont' change. So I think this solution works fine for me :)

Comment: Okay, a fixed set of structure declarations is fine.  Please close your question.

Answer (score 1):

Change the class definition to this and try it:

```
StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class TestData :BaseStructure
{
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public byte[] bytes = new byte[]{65,66,67}; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABC").ToArray();
```

Or, after I tested that. Maybe you mean this:

```
bytes = new byte[] { 65, 66, 67 };
string test = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).ToString();
```